# Класс как параметр метода

Tags: java, классы, методы

У меня есть класс Number c 2 методами setValue (принимает начальное число), showValue(отображает число value). И есть класс MethodCurrier в котором я должен написать метод, параметром которого будет класс Number и который увеличит число value на 5.
Не получается обратиться к классу в параметре метода. Вот код (убрал несколько фигурных скобок, чтоб корректно отобразился в вопросе) :

```
public class Number {
int value;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Number value = new Number();
    value.setValue(10);
    value.showValue();
    value.changeValue();
    value.showValue();
}

void setValue(int wrt) {
    value = wrt;
}

void showValue() {
    System.out.println(value);
class MethodCurrier {
void changeValue (тут должен быть класс Number в роли параметра){
    
}
```

Comment: можно вытаскивать поле из класса и сетить новое как вариант

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш вопрос изначально не очень корректный, потому как задача, описанная вами, нарушает паттрен GRASP "information expert". Если описать данный паттрен простыми словами, то информация должна обрабатываться там, где храниться, являющийся в свою очередь следствием принципа ООП инкапсуляции. Т.е. ваша переменная value инкапсулирована в классе Number, если проще - защищена от внешних воздействий. Частично это обеспечивается модификатором доступа private. Сеттеры, как бы это странно не звучало, нарушают инкапсуляциюи указанный выше паттерн, ведь фактически они дают вам возможность изменить значение переменной value из вне. Выход из этой ситуации для данного конкретного случая - добавить соответсвующий метод: public void addValue(int value). Он принимает int и прибавляет его к существующему значению. Таким образом, мы не нарушили принцип инкапсуляции, ведь фактически мы не меняем переменную из вне напрямую и не имеем к ней доступа, мы соблюдаем указанный паттерн, ведь информация, которая хранится в переменной value класса Number, обрабатывается (изменяется) методом этого же класса. Такой подход имеет множество преимуществ. Например, позволит вам избежать дублирования кода и производить эффективный рефакторинг вашего кода, потому как в противном случае метод, прибавляющий какое-то число к переменной value класса Number может потребоваться и в каком-либо третьем классе, вы вынуждены будете его снова написать (и так бесконечно). Кроме того, в пределах класса вы легко сможете найти дублирующую логику и вынести ее в приватные методы этого же класса. О бенефитах инкапсуляции рассказывать не буду.

И еще... Обратите внимание на одну важную деталь: предсказуемость поведения вашей программы. Для того, чтобы превратить объект в строку существует метод public String toString(), который понятен любому программисту. Прямой противоположенностью является ваш метод showValue(), глядя а который возникает только один вопрос - чтьо заставило человека пойти нестандартным путем? Поиск ответа на этот вопрос (т.е. поиск несуществующих подводных камней) займет много бесполезно потраченного времени.

Посему попробуйте такой подход (я специально убрал геттеры и сеттеры для чистоты эксперимента, вы можете добавить их сами):

```
public class Number {

    private int value;

    public Number(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void addValue(int value) {
        this.value += value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(value);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Number number = new Number(10);
        System.out.println(number);

        MethodCurrier methodCurrier = new MethodCurrier();
        methodCurrier.changeValue(number);
        System.out.println(number);
    }

}

class MethodCurrier {

    public void changeValue(Number number) {
        number.addValue(5);
    }
}
```